# Creating simple wandering AI in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a simple AI for a little character that just wanders around for my 2D game. I am currently using my own way where there is a thread for each character that chooses a random number between 0~2 every 0.5 seconds.

- If the number is 0 : character does not move.
- If the number is 1 : character moves right.
- If the number is 2 : character moves left.

But I figured out that if I use this, there will be too many threads if there are many characters, therefore making the game slower. Is there a more efficient way to make a simple AI for this type of character?

Comment: There is not nearly enough information about how you're doing this. Why did you try using threads? If anything, just have a `move()` method on your class, and call that on each character every tick.

Comment: Games are practically always single threaded, so your approach of thread per character is completely wrong.

Comment: `ExecutorService` is usually the answer to this kind of problem. Or not having threads at all, quite often it turns out that a single-threaded approach is good enough, and it's so much simpler.

Comment: On a different note, if you choose a new direction on every tick like you describe it, your characters are likely to move very jerkily, or they'll just do a Travolta: turning this way and that without going anywhere. So I'd rather store what characters' most recent move was and make them repeat it with (let's say) 80% probability, and only change direction/stop for the other 20%.

Comment: Thanks guys :) I have found a new way I can solve my problem thanks to all of your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a particular reason why each character has to be represented by a thread?  If you're dealing with massive amounts of updates, then you may possibly consider creating *one* thread that deals with generating random moves of all characters in parallel with your game, however I'm guessing that isn't going to be your case.

The simple and optimal way to do this is to simply generate a random move for each character.  If each character is its own class, then add a method called "moveRandomDirection()" that generates a random number and applies the move to its position.

Perhaps you're overthinking it.

Comment: oh, Thanks! I got a new idea for the random moving AI thanks to you :) I was just thinking of using a thread because I was thinking that I had to create a while loop for picking the random numbers that runs until the character's dead.